# Notification permission denied (Desktop Push Notification).Notification popup doesn't appear in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, desktop

I am trying to implement Desktop push Notifications for my website using Javascript.

Notification popup doesn't appear in chrome. I tried checking it in console window and it shows Denied. How can I change it so that user will be prompted with whether to accept or deny.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried

Comment: Please check your chrome version. It should be above 42.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your chrome version. It should be above 42.

Comment: This should be a comment